# Unable to use tilde (~) in vue image src binding

Tags: javascript, vue.js, data-binding, vue-component, nuxt.js

So the scenario is,

I have an array with test image names, I have to fetch a random image and bind to my image tag, 
The code I have used is:

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            images: ['test-1.png', 'test-2.png', 'test-3.png'],
        }
    },
    methods: {
        randomItem (items) {
            return items[Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length)];   
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.selectedImage = '~/assets/images/' + this.randomItem(this.images);
  }
```

And in my template I have added it as:

```
<img :src="selectedImage"/>
```

And my output on my browser renders it as:

```
<img data-v-658aaa7e="" src="~/assets/images/test-1.png">
```

I want it to take up the complete path.

Answer (score 1):

The path needs to be resolved with [`require`](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#require):

```js
this.selectedImage = require('~/assets/images/' + this.randomItem(this.images));
```

This is automatically done in the template by [`vue-loader`](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/asset-url.html), which is why it works without `require` there.

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/embed/polished-sky-tzlmt?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue&theme=dark)